# xlsxwriter - Modifying formatting whenever value changes

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have a script that is using xlsxwriter to produce a workbook with about a dozen columns, all from a certain manipulated df.

I sort the df and add it to a table before exporting to Excel.

```
 worksheet.add_table(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1, {'columns': column_settings})
```

It magically creates a table with alternate coloring (bands). I wish to control the formatting is the following fashion:

1. The df is sorted by a column called `case_id` (among other columns)
2. I wish to use no more than two bg colors
3. Every time the value in case_id changes, I wish to switch to the different color.

In other words - create bands by the value.

I thought about using [conditional formatting](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html) but it's not quite what I need. I'm agnostic the the value... In pseudocode, it can be something like this:

1. create two variables, one for each desired formatting (format1, format2), and temp_format = format1
2. go over the worksheet, row by row
3. 1. if value in case_id equals to case_id of the previous row, toggle temp_format to the other one.
   2. set row format to temp_format

Answer (score 0):

Implemented the pseudocode.

```
 format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#777CF4'})
 format2 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#3FCBFF'})
 tmp_format = format1
 tmp_val = 0
 for i in range(0, max_row):
    if df.loc[i]['chain_id'] != tmp_val:
        tmp_format = format2 if tmp_format == format1 else format1
        tmp_val = df.loc[i]['chain_id']
    worksheet.set_row(i+1, None, tmp_format) #Because writer is +1 comapared to df, due to headers
```