# Bound xlsxwriter set_row to last column

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I was using `set_row` to apply bg color formatting to a table given an "if" condition ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68247667/xlsxwriter-modifying-formatting-whenever-value-changes)). It colored the entire row while the table has 15 columns, so I came up with a walkaround (kudos to SO) of conditional formatting:

```py
(max_row, max_col) = df.shape
format1 = workbook.add_format({"bg_color": "#FFFFFF"})
format2 = workbook.add_format({"bg_color": "#E4DFEC"})
tmp_format = format1
tmp_val = 0
for i in range(0, max_row):
    if df.loc[i]["chain_id"] != tmp_val:
        tmp_format = format2 if tmp_format == format1 else format1
        tmp_val = df.loc[i]["chain_id"]
    worksheet.conditional_format(
        i + 1,
        0,
        i + 1,
        max_col - 1,
        {
            "type": "formula",
            "criteria": '=$A1<>"mustbeabetterway"',
            "format": tmp_format,
        },
    )
```

Not only is it super inelegant, but it also creates thousands of conditional formatting that cause laggy Excel workbook.
[image]

There's must be a better way to color a row between column indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some different ways on how to format the file, i have been using for loops (not ideal for very large dataframes but it can still get the job done). Basically what i was doing was to iterate through the rows and columns until the point that i wanted (usually the last row or last column) and apply the format to every cell using the worksheet's write method (for more info have a look here https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write ). You do not need conditional formatting unless you want to highlight different values with specific colors.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column A': [1,2,3,4],
                    'Column B': ['a','b','c','d'],
                    'Column C': ['A','B','C','D']})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Define your formats
format_red = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE'})
format_yellow = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFEB9C', 'italic': True})
format_green = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#C6EFCE', 'bold': True})

# Format the entire first column until the dataframe'w last cell
for row in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    worksheet.write(row+1, 0, df.iloc[row,0], format_red)

# Format the entire row from 2nd column until the dataframe's last column
for col in range(1, df.shape[1]):
    worksheet.write(2, col, df.iloc[1,col], format_green)

# Format the entire row from 1st column until the dataframe's last column
for col in range(0, df.shape[1]):
    worksheet.write(4, col, df.iloc[3,col], format_yellow)

writer.save()
```

Initial output:

[image]

Final output:

[image]